# Set initial values in form passing parameters (kwargs) with view

Tags: django, django-forms, keyword-argument

I want to prefill a form with values taken in a table.
First I pass the PK relative to the line where I wan't to get values and build the kwargs list:

**views.py**

```
def NavetteToFicheCreateView(request, pk):

    navette = Navette.objects.get(id=pk)
    ref = navette.id
    attribute_set = navette.famille.pk
    cost = navette.cost
    qty = navette.qty
    etat = navette.etat
    etat_ebay = navette.etat.etat_ebay
    ean = get_last_ean()

    form = NavetteToFicheForm(
        request.POST,
        ref=ref,
        attribute_set=attribute_set,
        cost=cost,
        qty=qty,
        etat=etat,
        etat_ebay=etat_ebay,
        ean=ean,
)
[...]
```

then I retrieve the kwargs in the **form.py** and setup my initial values

class NavetteToFicheForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.ref = kwargs.pop('ref', 'noref')
    self.attribute_set = kwargs.pop('attribute_set', 9999)
    self.cost = kwargs.pop('cost', 0)
    self.qty = kwargs.pop('qty', 0)
    self.etat = kwargs.pop('etat', 0)
    self.etat_ebay = kwargs.pop('etat_ebay', 9999)
    self.ean = kwargs.pop('ean', 9999)

    super(NavetteToFicheForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['ref'].initial = self.ref
    self.fields['attribute_set'].initial = self.attribute_set
    self.fields['cost'].initial = self.cost
    self.fields['qty'].initial = self.qty
    self.fields['etat'].initial = self.etat
    self.fields['etat_ebay'].initial = self.etat_ebay
    self.fields['ean'].initial = self.ean
[...]
```

My problem : some fields like "ref" or "attribute_set" are foreignKeys and are not transmitted when i display the form.

For checking my values :

```
print(self.ref)
print(self.attribute_set)
```

**output**

```
34
2
noref
9999
```

questions :

1. Why does the "print" displays 2 couples of values ? This looks like as if the "noref" and "999" are taken in account.
2. Why if i set manually 34 and 2 values, it works ?

   self.fields['ref'].initial = 34
   self.fields['attribute_set'].initial = 2

There's maybe a better way of doing this but I don't know it yet .

Comment: A quick thing, if you are using a modelForm then you just need to pass the instance of the object in so in your case NavetteToFicheForm(instance=navette) and then the form will load with that records data.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

If you are using other forms or the instance is new then use the initial kwarg instead to pass in a dictionary of initial values https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Comment: I am using ModelForm but i don't declare fields_names because I have about 40 fields. I use fields = 'all' (double underscore removed by Stack). So I applied your advices that consists in passing an initial dict. Only got still one issue on one fields. Its weird because the only fields that generate an issue is not present in my dict when i print it: It's missing on the 2nd line of the "print" (and I still don't know why the "print" I trigger under the "super form init" generates 2 lines. The field in question is present and populated in the 1st line.  :( .Thanks –